# Is there anyway of uploading images from the url?

Tags: html, angularjs, parse-platform

I want to upload images to my server from url rather than uploading from my computer. (eg: http://cache2.asset-cache.net/xt/150639030.jpg?v=1&g=fs1|0|CUL|39|030&s=1&b=RjI4 ). I want to do this in HTML with AngularJS and my backend is Parse

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may begin your journey **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Thank you for cooperating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this guide https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#images . 
You can create cloud method on Parse and pass url to it from your client.